# Indian passport

Tags: visas, passports, thailand, embassies, damaged-passports

[image]I have attached cover page of my passport. Other details are good. I have send my passport for business visa in Thai embassy. Let me any in there any issue for getting visa stamp and international travel?

Comment: Please search for questions using the **damaged-passports** tag.

Comment: If page is separated, its damaged. You should renew.

Comment: Page has not separate. Thread is holding the cover with passport very well. There is only one line Crack near the thread.

Comment: Then its not an issue.